# JS Jquery Собираем команду для запроса в бд

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 3 поля select и 1 запрос ajax хочу из 3х селектов собрать один запрос, что бы подставить в ajax

```
 $("#Month").change(function () {
   var Month = $("#Month").val();
    f2 = " and `date1` LIKE '___"+Month+"_____'";
    return(f2);
    Filters();
    });
```

Остальные селекты по аналогии
Как их объединить в переменную так, что бы если селект нажат он добавляется если нет, то не добавляется

Comment: Абсолютно непонятно, да и собирать SQL-запрос на фронтэнде - это как-то я даже не знаю...

Comment: `Filters()` после `return` не будет вызвана ни при каких обстоятельствах

Comment: А почему вы контруируете SQL-запрос на клиенте (если я правильно понимаю вопрос)? Это же крайне небезопасно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var Month, Days, Years; 
var data = {};
$("#Month").change(function () {
   data.Month = " and `date1` LIKE '___" + $(this).val() + "_____'";
}); 
$("#Days").change(function () {
   data.Days = " and `date1` LIKE '___" + $(this).val() + "_____'";
}); 
$("#Years").change(function () {
   data.Years = " and `date1` LIKE '___" + $(this).val() + "_____'";
}); 
$("#clickMe").click(function () {
 console.log("data", data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Month">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="Days">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="Years">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button id="clickMe">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно завести внешнюю переменную, в которой собирать изменённые данные.

```js
{
  const selY = $('#year');
  const selM = $('#month');
  const selD = $('#day');

  const btn = $('#send');
  
  const filterDate = {};
  selY.change(() => filterDate.y = selY.val());
  selM.change(() => filterDate.m = selM.val());
  selD.change(() => filterDate.d = selD.val());


  const getFilterDateValue = () => 
    ['y', 'm', 'd']
     .map(k => filterDate[k])
     .filter(a => a)
     .join('');
  btn.click(() => console.log('value: ', getFilterDateValue()));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="day">
  <option value=01>1</option>
  <option value=02>2</option>
  <option value=03>3</option>
</select>
<select id="month">
  <option value=01>Янв</option>
  <option value=02>Фев</option>
  <option value=03>Mар</option>
</select>
<select id="year">
  <option value=2018>2018</option>
  <option value=2019>2019</option>
</select>

<hr/>
<button id=send>Send</button>
```